# How do I mock my repository and apiClient from inside my viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I have a **MainViewModel**:

```
 class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {
.....
val source: LiveData<GenericApiResponse<GitResult>> = mainRepository.fetchApiresultFromClient(str_query)  
}
```

**Mainrepository:**

```
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(val mainApiClient: MainApiClient) {
    ....
    fun fetchApiresultFromClient(strQuery: String)
     : LiveData<GenericApiResponse<GitResult>> {

      var returnedData =    mainApiClient.getApiResultFromServer(strQuery)
      return returnedData
     }
```

**MainApiClient:**

```
class MainApiClient  @Inject constructor(val mainApi: MainApi) {

   fun getApiResultFromServer(query :String )
        : LiveData<GenericApiResponse<GitResult>> {

    var apiResult =   mainApi.getAllRepo(query)

       return apiResult

    }
}
```

Now I want to test the below function in viewModel `mainRepository.fetchApiresultFromClient(str_query)`

I want to test that when the above function is called from viewModel then it returns the same result that's returned from `mainApiClient.getApiResultFromServer()`

But to do that I need to mock both repository and apiClient. I tried the below but unfortunately seems its not working.

```
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)
class MainViewModelTest {

    lateinit var  mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    @Mock
     lateinit var  mainRepository: MainRepository

    @Mock
    lateinit var  mainApiClient: MainApiClient


    @BeforeEach
    fun init()
    {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    mainViewModel = MainViewModel(mainRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun setSearchQuery_callsRepositoryMethod_returnSuccess() {

           //arrange
         mainViewModel.liveResult.value = ApiSuccessResponse(TestUtil.obj_gitresult) as GenericApiResponse<GitResult>

        Mockito.`when`(mainApiClient.getApiResultFromServer(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()))
            .thenReturn(mainViewModel.liveResult)


           //act

        var repo_response = mainRepository.fetchApiresultFromClient("java")


        //assert
           // assertTrue(repo_response.value is  GenericApiResponse<GitResult> ) //for asserting return type is of type GenericResponse //--TestResult- java.lang.NullPointerException
           // assertTrue(repo_response.value is  ApiSuccessResponse<GitResult> ) //for asserting return type is of type ApiSuccessResponse //--TestResult- java.lang.NullPointerException
           //  assertEquals(mainViewModel.liveResult.value , repo_response.value ) //for asserting 2 generic types are equal //--TestResult- java.lang.NullPointerException
        }

}
```

Am I doing something wrong by mocking both `MainRepository` and `MainApiClient`. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: On a general note I'd say yes. You shouldn't mock what you're testing. My question is, why testing the repository from the view model? If you're doing a unit test, the repository should be tested isolated. The kind of test you describe is actually a good candidate to test the repository in isolation.

Comment: @Fred : sorry I am new in testing. But my confusion is that if I need to test everything in isolation then how am I going to know what is returned from a method in repository to the viewmodel. Whats the point if I have to mock the result too and then assert against it?

Comment: So usually that's done via verifying interactions. With mockito you can check that the repository gets called from the view model. Then with unit testing the repository, you're sure it returns what it's meant to return. When you put things together, the consensus is that they should work. If you test everything together I think that falls more into the realm of integration testing. If you'd like I can post an answer with an example, it's just that it won't answer your question...

Comment: @Fred  :thanks for your reply. Ok I think I understand that doing test in isolation is a good idea. But can I test with original result? lets say in my MainApiClient I am getting result from webservice call with retrofit in mainAPi. So can I test in MainApiClient that the webservice result was success or error by not mocking the result?

Comment: Well the idea is to actually mock the result so you can fake a success and a failure.